# which is the best ubuntu for intel atom processor

Tags: cpu

Which is the **best Ubuntu for Intel Atom powered notebooks**? I have already tried 13.04 but that did not work. please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try Xubunu.  Xubuntu is based on Ubuntu, but it uses the XFCE desktop environment.

> Xubuntu is an elegant and easy-to-use operating system. Xubuntu comes
>   with Xfce, which is a stable, light and configurable desktop
>   environment.
>
> Xubuntu is perfect for those who want the most out of their desktops,
>   laptops and netbooks with a modern look and enough features for
>   efficient, daily usage. It works well on older hardware too.

For more info, and to download, see the [Website](http://xubuntu.org/)

<sup>Source:[Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/)</sup>